# Dockex demo in Delphi

Tags: delphi, demo, docking

I found the demo Dockex.Dproj in Delphi under:
...Documents\RAD Studio\11.0\Samples\Delphi\VCL\Docking

But there is no document on how to run the Demo and what to do to see all the features demonstrated there. I tried running but can't make sense of what it does. The code looks complicated so can't go by that. Will appreciate any help on this.

Comment: In Delphi 10 Seattle, I don't have such a sample project. Which version of Delphi are you running?

Comment: What instructions do you need? Compile and run the demo. Click one of the buttons labeled with the name of a color, which creates a window filled with that color. Drag it to various edges of the parent window; you'll see the shape change when it can be dropped to dock it there. Drop it wherever that shape appears. Drag windows inside other windows, where you can drop them as well. Drag a docked window back out by it's upper edge, and it becomes undocked again.

Comment: @Jerry: It comes with earlier versions. The poster indicated v11 in the directory path mentioned, and Seattle is v17. V5 is Delphi 2007 (based on the version number indicated in the folder path, not compiler or RTL version), so v11 would appear to be around XE or XE2.

Comment: @Jerry: I can, in my D2007 install (5.0 in the folder name). The demo didn't change in later versions until whenever it was removed by EMBT in favor of the mobile/FMX demos. (And I mentioned that Seattle's path included v17 in my previous comment.)

Comment: (continued) If you open a new window, and then drag another window over it so that it's shadowed image appears centered in the first one and drop it, a page control is created that contains the two forms (you'll see color-named tabs appear in the top left that allow you to switch forms by clicking the tab).

Comment: @Ken Originally your comment said I think 18 when I replied, then you edited and now it's 17, so I deleted my comment.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks. It works. I was confused by the presence of Toolbar buttons. What do they do? Can a page control be created in a docked window?

Comment: If I want a behavior exactly as docking but want to retain the height of the original form, is that possible--something like dragging tool buttons into a toolbar where they snap automatically. Or, is that a drag and drop operation instead of docking. Just curious.

Comment: *Toolbar buttons. What do they do?* The source code is pretty clear; did you look at it? *Can a page control...?* Certainly. Why would you not be able to create a page control in a docked window?

Comment: Yes, once I looked at the comments in the code, I could make out. Still some of the code is not clear as to what it does and what happens in its absence. The demo is good but I could not find any good overview documentation on docking that explains how to control the preview rectangle that is shown before docking and to finally dock and why would someone use a custom Docking Manager etc. There is a Class reference documentation on Delphi sites but no overview like that. Will post another question with specifics. Thanks. You can post your original comment as answer so that I accept it.